# IdentityServer4 not handling implicit logon flow after updating VS2019 to version 16.4.2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, identityserver4

I have had IdentityServer4 running for a few months and it's working perfectly. After updating VS2019 from 16.3.10 to 16.4.2 the implicit logon flow is not working any more. The user gets authenticated, but when the callback connect/authorize is initiated the user is not authenticated any more and the user trying to logon get the logon screen again. It took me four hours to find what was causing this. I had a system at home which ran the software fine, while running the same software on my workstation at work showed the faulty behaviour. When I updated my home system to the latest version I ended up with the version not working any more.

I cannot update Identityserver. I already tried the latest version 2.5.4 instead of stable 3.0.2 but that does not cure the problem. I also tried .net core 3.1 instead of 3.0. No difference.

I'm testing with the Oauth2 capability with the "implicit" logon feature of Postman which worked perfectly fine up to now. I always received a JWT token without problems.

Beneath is the log:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:51131/account/enterpassword application/x-www-form-urlencoded 466
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware[10]
      No CORS policy found for the specified request.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.EnterPassword (Identity)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "EnterPassword", controller = "Account"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] EnterPassword(IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.LoginInputModel, System.String) on controller IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController (Identity).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[10]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv signed in.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.RedirectResultExecutor[1]
      Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /connect/authorize/callback?response_type=token&state&client_id=openIdConnectClient&scope=apiservice.user&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdev-api.bank2loyalty.com%2Fsignin-oidc.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.EnterPassword (Identity) in 567.556ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.EnterPassword (Identity)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 585.8635ms 302 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:51131/connect/authorize/callback?response_type=token&state&client_id=openIdConnectClient&scope=apiservice.user&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdev-api.bank2loyalty.com%2Fsignin-oidc  
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint for /connect/authorize/callback
info: IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator[0]
      Showing login: User is not authenticated
```

I managed to install 16.3.10 by downloading it from the VS2019 site.
And guess what, it works again see below log. But how to resolve this?

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:51131/account/enterpassword  
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.EnterPassword (Identity)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "EnterPassword", controller = "Account"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] EnterPassword() on controller IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController (Identity).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ViewResult, running view EnterPassword.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[4]
      Executed ViewResult - view EnterPassword executed in 19.181900000000002ms.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.EnterPassword (Identity) in 475.66540000000003ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.EnterPassword (Identity)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 490.25820000000004ms 200 text/html; charset=utf-8
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:51131/account/enterpassword application/x-www-form-urlencoded 466
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware[10]
      No CORS policy found for the specified request.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.EnterPassword (Identity)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "EnterPassword", controller = "Account"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] EnterPassword(IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.LoginInputModel, System.String) on controller IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController (Identity).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[10]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv signed in.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.RedirectResultExecutor[1]
      Executing RedirectResult, redirecting to /connect/authorize/callback?response_type=token&state&client_id=openIdConnectClient&scope=apiservice.user&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdev-api.bank2loyalty.com%2Fsignin-oidc.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.EnterPassword (Identity) in 514.2881ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI.AccountController.EnterPassword (Identity)'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 533.3788000000001ms 302 
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:51131/connect/authorize/callback?response_type=token&state&client_id=openIdConnectClient&scope=apiservice.user&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdev-api.bank2loyalty.com%2Fsignin-oidc  
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint for /connect/authorize/callback
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler[10]
      AuthenticationScheme: idsrv signed in.
```

Some debug output from the failed situation which might a user "skilled in the art" to give an idea what goes wrong.

```
[11:06:05 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was not authenticated.
[11:06:05 Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: idsrv signed in.
[11:06:05 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was not authenticated.
[11:06:05 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was not authenticated.
[11:06:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Request path /connect/authorize/callback matched to endpoint type Authorize
[11:06:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter
Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint
[11:06:05 Information] IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware
Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint for /connect/authorize/callback
[11:06:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint
Start authorize callback request
[11:06:05 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was not authenticated.
[11:06:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint
No user present in authorize request
[11:06:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
Start authorize request protocol validation
[11:06:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
[11:06:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeCallbackEndpoint
ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
{"ClientId": "openIdConnectClient", "ClientName": "Example Implicit Client Application", "RedirectUri": "https://localhost:44378/signin-oidc", "AllowedRedirectUris": ["https://localhost:44378/signin-oidc", "https://dev-api.bank2loyalty.com/signin-oidc", "https://api.bank2loyalty.com/signin-oidc"], "SubjectId": "anonymous", "ResponseType": "token", "ResponseMode": "fragment", "GrantType": "implicit", "RequestedScopes": "apiservice.user", "State": null, "UiLocales": null, "Nonce": null, "AuthenticationContextReferenceClasses": null, "DisplayMode": null, "PromptMode": null, "MaxAge": null, "LoginHint": null, "SessionId": null, "Raw": {"response_type": "token", "state": "", "client_id": "openIdConnectClient", "scope": "apiservice.user", "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:44378/signin-oidc"}, "$type": "AuthorizeRequestValidationLog"}
[11:06:05 Information] IdentityServer4.ResponseHandling.AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator
Showing login: User is not authenticated
[11:06:05 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was not authenticated.
[11:06:05 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was not authenticated.
[11:06:05 Debug] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler
AuthenticationScheme: idsrv was not authenticated.
[11:06:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
Start authorize request protocol validation
[11:06:05 Debug] IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator
Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
```

Comment: Does it run outside VS?

Comment: No. I ran it as a container, Same problem.

Comment: So you only update VS, build your code, deploy into a container, same code, exact versions of all referenced components and somehow the code works or not depending on which VS was used to build it?

Comment: Yeah it looked like that. But it's getting worse, I tried to downgrade my workpc. I had to cleanout the ms vs 2019 directory in order to install 16.3.10. After install sdk's where missing and I installed them from the .net core website. Then even with 16.3.10 the code does not run. It's driving me nuts!

Comment: Could you compare then your external references, one by one, and check which specific reference has **different** version in the build that doesn't work? This could be the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was not with VS2019 but with the installed version of .netCore. As of .net Core 3.0.1 and higher cookie policy handling has changed!

With the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-3.1. and the help of Chriss Ross I managed to solve the issue.  I modified the sections as suggested and now it works like a charm, I tested chrome, firefox, edge and internetexplore. All good!

Step 1:
Modify Configure section in startup and add UseCookiePolicy

```
app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Step 2:
Modify Configure services:

```
// Cookie policy stuff
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = (SameSiteMode) (-1);
    options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext =>
        CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
    options.OnDeleteCookie = cookieContext =>
        CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);
});
```

Step 3: Add Checking code in startup

```
private void CheckSameSite(HttpContext httpContext, CookieOptions options)
{
    if (options.SameSite == SameSiteMode.None)
    {
        var userAgent = httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();
        if (DisallowsSameSiteNone(userAgent))
        {
            options.SameSite = (SameSiteMode) (-1);
        }
    }
}

private bool DisallowsSameSiteNone(string userAgent)
{
    // Cover all iOS based browsers here. This includes:
    // - Safari on iOS 12 for iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad
    // - WkWebview on iOS 12 for iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad
    // - Chrome on iOS 12 for iPhone, iPod Touch, iPad
    // All of which are broken by SameSite=None, because they use the iOS networking
    // stack.
    if (userAgent.Contains("CPU iPhone OS 12") ||
    userAgent.Contains("iPad; CPU OS 12"))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Cover Mac OS X based browsers that use the Mac OS networking stack. 
    // This includes:
    // - Safari on Mac OS X.
    // This does not include:
    // - Chrome on Mac OS X
    // Because they do not use the Mac OS networking stack.
    if (userAgent.Contains("Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14") &&
        userAgent.Contains("Version/") && userAgent.Contains("Safari"))
    {
        return true;
    }

    // Cover Chrome 50-69, because some versions are broken by SameSite=None, 
    // and none in this range require it.
    // Note: this covers some pre-Chromium Edge versions, 
    // but pre-Chromium Edge does not require SameSite=None.
    if (userAgent.Contains("Chrome/5") || userAgent.Contains("Chrome/6"))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This answer saved my life! And please note that "app.UseCookiePolicy();" must appear after "app.UseIdentityServer();". I spent hours to figure this out...